# Moviepy: how to do advanced composition between two clips (e.g. insert a movie inside a (possibly moving) green rectangle in another video)

Tags: moviepy

I am attempting to insert, with MoviePy, a video (`dog.mp4`) into another video's green screen, while resizing `dog.mp4` to fit perfectly inside the green rectangle. It seems like this cannot be accomplished using the `image_transform` custom effect ([doc](https://moviepy-tburrows13.readthedocs.io/en/improve-docs/getting_started/effects.html)), as it only allows for one input video. Any suggestions on how to approach this issue?